# Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected argument type 'KotlinDouble?'

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a kotlin multiplarform project

This is a KMP class:

```
class CreateRequest(
      val length: Double? = null,
      val coreDiameter: Double? = null,
      ...
)
```

And I call it from the iOS code like this:

```
CreateRequest(
     length: Double(self.rollerLength),
     coreDiameter: .init(double: Double(self.rollerCoreDiameter) ?? 0.0),
     ...
)
```

`coreDiameter` input works fine, but I don't want it to be 0 if it cannot parse it because the input can be empty and in that case it should stay null

`length` throws an error saying `Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected argument type 'KotlinDouble?'`

I want to pass Optional Double from swift to a nullable String in KMP as a class parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, there's a method for converting optionals inline, the naming might be surprising for those familiar with other programming languages. This method is called [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/map(_:)). Here's an example:

```
coreDiameter: Double(self.rollerCoreDiameter).map { KotlinDouble(double: $0) }
```

Alternatively, you can pass the initializer of `KotlinDouble` directly to the map function:

```
coreDiameter: Double(self.rollerCoreDiameter).map(KotlinDouble.init(double:))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider unwrapping, rather than nil coalescing. Something to the following effect:

```
let coreDiameter: KotlinDouble?

if let double = Double(self.rollerCoreDiameter),
  let kotlinDouble = KotlinDouble(double: double) {
    coreDiameter = kotlinDouble
} else {
    coreDiameter = nil
}

...

CreateRequest(
  length: Double(self.rollerLength),
  coreDiameter: coreDiameter,
 ...
)
```